# Error installing PHP7.1 with apache2 on debian 9

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, openssl, compilation

Hello I installed the apache with debian's 9 installation. Then installed php7.0 with apt-get but I need to install php7.1, at first I do

```
$ su
$ apt-get purge php7.0
```

so I downloaded from http://php.net/downloads.php php 7.1.10 and make this

```
$ ./configure --with-mcrypt
$ make
$ make install
```

but `phpinfo()` get the php7.0, so I make

```
$ su
$ apt-get purge php7.0 
$ apt-get autoremove php7.0
```

and know `phpinfo()` is not working. I sumed that now php is not installed.

Then downloaded from http://php.net/downloads.php php 7.1.11 (new today) and inside

```
$ tar jxvf php-7.1.11.tar.bz2
$ apt-get install build-essential
$ apt-get install libxml2-dev libmcrypt-dev libjpeg-dev
$ cd php-7.1.11
$ ./configure --with-mcrypt --with-pdo-pgsql=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main --with-openssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-zlib --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

And between all the checks I get the next errors

```
Configuring SAPI modules
checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS... [Fri Oct 27 12:30:45.328686 2017] [core:warn] [pid 12056] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
yes

configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get install libssl-dev

You must install openssl development files in order to compile php

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl-dev

Also, once you compile php successfully, don't forget to change apache module to the right directory for php.so

There must be a line looking line LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so in apache configuration

Comment: I make it as an answer but my problem was between 2 different php 7.1.10 and 7.1.11 installed.

Comment: you want to install both php 7.1.10 and 7.1.11 or just 7.1.11?

Comment: no I made that, I just want one. But All ok now. thanks

Comment: fell free to edit the answer according to the steps that really solved your problem in case it help someone else